# How can I submit form without button in unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, formik

The `fireEvent.submit(form)` call doesn't seem to be submitting the form. How can I submit the form?

**BasicInfo/index.test.tsx**

```js
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

import BasicInfo from '.';

describe('BasicInfo', () => {
  it('can submit form', async () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
    render(<BasicInfo onSubmit={handleSubmit} />);
    const user = userEvent.setup();

    await user.type(screen.getByLabelText('Event title'), 'Event title 1');
    await user.type(screen.getByLabelText('Featured game'), 'Scrabble');
    await user.type(screen.getByLabelText('Venue location'), '21 2nd St.');
    await user.type(screen.getByLabelText('Event starts'), '2017-06-01T08:30');
    await user.type(screen.getByLabelText('Event ends'), '2017-06-01T08:30');

    const form = screen.getByTestId<HTMLFormElement>('basic-info');
    fireEvent.submit(form);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        title: 'Event title 1',
        game: { name: 'Scrabble' },
        address: '21 2nd St.',
        starts_at: '2017-06-01T08:30',
        ends_at: '2017-06-01T08:30',
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**BasicInfo/index.tsx**

```js
import { Form, Formik, FormikErrors, FormikHelpers, FormikProps } from 'formik';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';

import { useLocation } from '../../context/location';
import { Event } from '../../hooks/useEvents';
import useGames, { Game } from '../../hooks/useGames';
import useMapbox, { Feature, Coords } from '../../hooks/useMapbox';
import useThrottle from '../../hooks/useThrottle';
import { parseAddress } from '../../lib/helpers';
import AddressItem from '../AddressItem';
import AutoComplete from '../AutoComplete';
import Button from '../Button';

import FormSection from '../FormSection';
import InputGroup from '../InputGroup';
import GameItem from '../GameItem';

export interface BasicInfoValues {
  title: string;
  game: Game;
  address: string;
  starts_at: string;
  ends_at: string;
  coords: string;
}

interface Props {
  event?: Event;
  initialValues?: BasicInfoValues;
  onSubmit: (values: BasicInfoValues) => Promise<void>;
}

function BasicInfo({ event, initialValues: initialVals, onSubmit }: Props) {
  const { coords } = useLocation();
  const { data: places, forward, getStaticMapUrl } = useMapbox();
  const { data: games, search, leanGame } = useGames();
  const throttle = useThrottle();

  const initialValues: BasicInfoValues = initialVals || {
    title: '',
    game: { name: '' },
    address: '',
    starts_at: '',
    ends_at: '',
    coords: '',
  };

  const validate = (values: BasicInfoValues) => {
    const errors: FormikErrors<BasicInfoValues> = {};

    if (values.title.length < 3) {
      errors.title = 'Must be at least 3 characters';
    }
    if (values.title.length > 50) {
      errors.title = 'Must be less than 50 characters';
    }

    if (!values.game.name) {
      errors.game = 'Must select a game' as FormikErrors<Game>;
    }

    if (!values.coords) {
      errors.coords = 'Must select a location';
    }

    if (!values.starts_at) {
      errors.starts_at = 'Required';
    }

    if (!values.ends_at) {
      errors.ends_at = 'Required';
    }

    return errors;
  };

  const handleSubmit = async function (
    values: BasicInfoValues,
    formikHelpers: FormikHelpers<BasicInfoValues>
  ) {
    try {
      await onSubmit(values);
      formikHelpers.setSubmitting(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const renderLocation = function ({
    setFieldValue,
    values,
    handleChange,
    errors,
    touched,
    handleBlur,
  }: FormikProps<BasicInfoValues>) {
    const handleEditLocationClick = function () {
      setFieldValue('address', '');
      setFieldValue('coords', '');
    };

    const { coords: coordinates, address } = values;
    if (coordinates && address) {
      const staticMapUrl = getStaticMapUrl({
        coords: JSON.parse(coordinates),
        width: 600,
        height: 165,
      });
      const { street, city } = parseAddress(address);
      return (
        <div className="basic-info__location">
          <div className="basic-info__location__image-container">
            <Image
              src={staticMapUrl}
              alt="static map"
              layout="fill"
              objectFit="fill"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="basic-info__location__address-container">
            <div className="basic-info__location__address-container__address">
              <span className="basic-info__location__street">{street}</span>
              <span className="basic-info__location__city">{city}</span>
            </div>
            <Button
              text="Edit location"
              color="secondary"
              size="small"
              onClick={handleEditLocationClick}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <AutoComplete<Feature>
          name="address"
          value={values.address}
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (!handleChange) return;
            handleChange(e);
            throttle.wait(() => {
              if (!e.target.value) return;
              if (!coords) return;
              forward({
                coords,
                q: e.target.value,
              });
            }, 500);
          }}
          label="Venue location"
          placeholder="Search for a venue or address"
          items={places}
          Input={InputGroup}
          itemRenderer={(item) => <AddressItem placeName={item.place_name} />}
          onItemClick={(item) => {
            if (!setFieldValue) return;
            setFieldValue('address', item.place_name);
            setFieldValue('coords', JSON.stringify(item.center));
          }}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          error={errors.coords && touched.address ? errors.coords : undefined}
        />
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      validate={validate}
    >
      {(formikProps) => {
        const {
          values,
          handleChange,
          setFieldValue,
          errors,
          touched,
          handleBlur,
        } = formikProps;
        return (
          <Form id="basic-info" className="basic-info" data-testid="basic-info">
            <FormSection
              title="Basic Info"
              description="Name your event and tell gamers what game will be played. Add
            details that highlight what makes it unique."
              icon="segment"
            >
              <InputGroup
                name="title"
                value={values.title}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                label="Event title"
                placeholder="Be clear and descriptive"
                error={errors.title && touched.title ? errors.title : undefined}
              />
              <AutoComplete<Game>
                name="game.name"
                value={values.game.name}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  handleChange(e);
                  throttle.wait(() => {
                    if (!e.target.value) return;
                    search({ name: e.target.value, limit: 5 });
                  }, 500);
                }}
                label="Featured game"
                placeholder="Search games"
                Input={InputGroup}
                items={games}
                itemRenderer={(item) => <GameItem game={item} />}
                onItemClick={(item) => {
                  const game = leanGame(item);
                  setFieldValue('game', game);
                }}
                error={
                  errors.game && touched.game
                    ? (errors.game as string)
                    : undefined
                }
              />
              <span>
                Need game ideas?{' '}
                <Link href="/" passHref>
                  <a className="link">Browse games by category</a>
                </Link>
              </span>
            </FormSection>
            <FormSection
              title="Location"
              description="Help gamers in the area discover your event and let attendees know where to show up."
              icon="map"
            >
              {renderLocation(formikProps)}
            </FormSection>
            <FormSection
              title="Date and time"
              description="Tell gamers when your event starts and ends so they can make plans to attend."
              icon="date_range"
            >
              <InputGroup
                name="starts_at"
                value={values.starts_at}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                label="Event starts"
                placeholder="Search for a venue or address"
                type="datetime-local"
                // icon="calendar_today"
                error={
                  errors.starts_at && touched.starts_at
                    ? errors.starts_at
                    : undefined
                }
              />
              <InputGroup
                name="ends_at"
                value={values.ends_at}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                label="Event ends"
                placeholder="Search for a venue or address"
                type="datetime-local"
                // icon="calendar_today"
                error={
                  errors.ends_at && touched.ends_at ? errors.ends_at : undefined
                }
              />
            </FormSection>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default BasicInfo;
```

[image: The failing test]

Answer (score 0):

My form validation was preventing me from submitting